# How to make an loop for awaiting messages in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a game btw.

I have a large map and a small map.

A small map focuses on a 5x5 print of a 100x100 map and when you send one of "w a s d" it does the necessary action depending on the key.

My code is this:

```js
message.channel
  .awaitMessages((msg) => msg.author.id == message.author.id, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
  })
  .then((collected) => {
    if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == "w") {
      simdiX--;
    } else if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == "s") {
      simdiX++;
    } else if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == "d") {
      simdiY++;
    } else if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == "a") {
      simdiY--;
    } else if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == "cancel") {
      message.channel.bulkDelete(2);
      return message.channel.send("Canceled:ok_hand:");
    } else {
      async function del() {
        let ms = await message.channel.send("That's not an option");
        wait(5000);
        ms.delete();
      }
      del();
    }

    tasi(simdiX, simdiY, 5, 5);
    message.channel.bulkDelete(2);
    myPrint(5, 5);
  })
  .catch(() => {
    message.reply("U lost ur chance");
  });
```

OK my formatting is a little bit strange

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TextBasedChannel#createMessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextBasedChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector) to create a `MessageCollector`, which is an async iterable. You can use [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) with this collector:

```js
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(
  msg => msg.author.id == message.author.id,
  {time: 30000}
);
for await (const msg of collector) {
  if (msg.content.toLowerCase() == "w") {
    simdiX--;
  }
  // etc...
}
// This will be sent when the collector ends (when time runs out or if you
// manually stop it with collector.stop())
message.reply("U lost ur chance");
```

Note that you can only use `for await...of` in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: So it does make a loop but it doesn't understand the content it thinks that the content is not one of the w a s d characters.

Comment: @cinoez What do you mean by it 'doesn't understand the content'? Could you try debugging and seeing what `msg.content` is?